# How to show a base64 image using JSON formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I tried the following, but SharePoint seems to dislike the `:`

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "='data:image/png;base64,'+[$IconAsBase64]"
}
```

If I change `data:` for `data~` the image show as a broken image (as expected), but with `data:` the entire component is omitted.

Comment: What is the column/data type of `IconAsBase64` column?

Comment: It's a multiline plain text.

Comment: ok, unfortunately base64 images do not work in SharePoint JSON formatting. Check my answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, base64 image URLs are not supported by SharePoint JSON formatting.

SharePoint JSON formatting only supports `http` and `https` protocols for image URLs:

[image]

**Related thread**: [Img src attribute provided as data url are not supported](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/issues/226)

If you want Microsoft to provide the support for base64 images in JSON formatting, you can add new idea/feedback at: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: I'm a Sharepoint newbie and didn't know about `debugMode`. It will be very helpful on other situations. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you! Try to avoid using `debugMode` in production after your development/testing as general users will not understand the errors returned by it.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I can't access your blog from Brazil. It throws a connection time out error. I eventually found it yesterday and had to use the Google cache to read an article. I checked on different tools, but they say the site is up. Any idea of what could be happening (any blocks or so)?

Comment: Are you referring to this blog site: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/?

Comment: Yes: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/

Comment: Not sure what is the issue but I have many site visitors from the Brazil (I just checked). Maybe some network/cache/site settings issue at your end. Thanks for reporting and checking the blog site. Please let me know if I can help you with anything else.